# How to center elements multirow element vertically in a table

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment, multirow

In each row in my table, I have a multirow that spans two columns, and also in the last column I am adding an image.

The table looks something like this:
[image]

Now, you'll notice the horizontal line separating the multirow is not symmetrically aligned to the image. I'd like to have equal amount of space in the upper and lower 'sub-row' of each row. How can I do this?

The code I am using looks something like this (the example has only one row):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\caption{Table with transformation details}
\label{transformations}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
\hline
Variable & Transformation & Skewness & Kurtosis & Winsorisation & Polarity & Distributions \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Crime} & Raw Data & 6.945 & 57.658 & \multirow{2}{*}{maxval = 0.002} & \multirow{2}{*}{-} & \multirow{2}{*}{} \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
 & Transformed & -1.581 & 5.385 &  &  & \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=25mm]{Images/dist/distributions_crime1.png} \end{minipage} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this below?

Note, your table is much wider than the available space, hence I have applied `sidewaystable` to add rotation, instead of scaling the whole table, which is not recommended. If you prefer upright table, perhaps re-consider changing long content in headers and cells with texts.

The centring in bottom cells is achieved by moving baseline of images to the middle point via extra optional argument `valign=c` (requires to load  `adjustbox` with optional `[export]`).

`\vcorrection` is to correct `multirow` which sometimes needs an extra offset if extra spacing is introduced in the table. The factor `-0.5` might need slight tuning.

A couple of minor changes and suggestions. Consider using prefix in labels, s.a. `tab:...` for tables or `fig:...` for figures. You can shorten repeated column definition, e.g. `*{n}{<col-type>}`, e.g. `*{7}{l}`--if `n` is one digit, it can be even shorter: `*7{l}`. If you load `booktabs`, you have access to other custom rules: `\toprule`, `\bottomrule`, `\midrule`, each of which accept optional argument rule width, e.g. `\midrule[1.2pt]`; they differ in adding extra space above or/and below rules.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}

\newlength\vcorrection


\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \setlength\vcorrection{-0.5\dimexpr\aboverulesep+\belowrulesep}
    \captionsetup{skip=3pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \caption{Table with transformation details}
    \label{tab:transformations}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{*7{l}}
        \toprule
        Variable & Transformation & Skewness & Kurtosis & Winsorisation & Polarity & Distributions \\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}*[\vcorrection]{Crime}
        & Raw Data
        & 6.945
        & 57.658
        & \multirow{2}*[\vcorrection]{maxval = 0.002}
        & -
        & \\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
              & Transformed & -1.581 & 5.385  &                &   & \includegraphics[width=4\dimexpr25mm/3, height=25mm, valign=c]{Images/dist/distributions_crime1.png} \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{2}*[\vcorrection]{Train station}
        & Raw Data
        & 2.398
        & 10.558
        & \multirow{2}*[\vcorrection]{maxval = 50000}
        & -
        & \\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
              & Transformed & -0.528 & 2.470  &                &   & \includegraphics[width=4\dimexpr25mm/3, height=25mm, valign=c]{Images/dist/distributions_crime1.png} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]